# How do post method works in php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, post, http-post

How can i fix this?

```
//error_reporting(0);
$token = $_POST['token'];
$invite = $_POST['invite'];

$url = "https://mywebsite.com/asd/".$invite."";
$dingaling = "$token"

?>
```

When: https://mywebsite.com/asdsdsss.php?token=test&invite=test2

**ERROR:**

*Notice: Undefined index: token in D:\asdsdsss.php on line 3*

*Notice: Undefined index: invite in D:\asdsdsss.php on line 4*

Comment: `$_POST` isn't a method.  It's an associative array that contains the query string values from the post body of the client requests to your endpoint.  The url you've provided has the query string in the url, which would be parsed into the `$_GET` associative array, not the `$_POST`.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php  https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: @Taplar now when i make the post throught javascript it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you submit form?

Comment: @VinayKaklotar here:

    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("POST", "asdsdsss.php", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.send("token=" + thetokenbruh + "&invite=" + theinvitebruh);

Comment: @dawaeboi You should try with `ajax`!

Comment: @VinayKaklotar how?

Answer (score 0):

**Try with ajax**

You can use send data using `ajax` in post method.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'asdsdsss.php',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        "token": thetokenbruh,
        "invite": theinvitebruh
    },
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function (errordata) {

    }
});
```

**PHP code (asdsdsss.php)**

```
<?php
//error_reporting(0);
if ($_POST) {
    $token = '';
    if (isset($_POST['token'])) {
        $token = $_POST['token'];
    }

    $invite = '';
    if (isset($_POST['invite'])) {
        $invite = $_POST['invite'];
    }

    $url = "https://mywebsite.com/asd/" . $invite . "";
    $dingaling = "$token";
}
?>
```